# Filter Fullcalendar 4 from external function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to filter the calendar from an external function using fullcalendar version 4. But I cant seem to access the calendar instance. Anybody knows how I can do this?

I think one needs to use the: `var mycalendar = calendar.view;`

At the moment I can filter but I have to create the calendar again. I would like to use the original calendar loaded and simply refresh the results.

```
function CalendarModalFilter() {

  var post = $('#calendar_filter_form').serialize();
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(post);
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('kt_calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
  });

  NotifyPage('Filtered Calendar!', 'success');

  var FilterSource = {
    url: './demo2/contents/calendar/get.php',
    method: 'POST',
    extraParams: {
      source: searchParams.get("calType")
    }
  };

  var eventSources = calendar.getEventSources();

  var len = eventSources.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    eventSources[i].remove();
  }

  calendar.addEventSource(FilterSource);
  calendar.refetchEvents();
  calendar.render();
};
```

This is a portion of the calendar initialization:

```
var initCalendar = function() {

  var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
  var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
  var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('kt_calendar');
  var containerEl = document.getElementById('kt_calendar_external_events');

  var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;

  new Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: '.fc-draggable-handle',
    eventData: function(eventEl) {
      return $(eventEl).data('event');
    }
  });

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    eventSources: [fcSources.planificacion],
    //...
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] or at least some code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vanilla fullCalendar then in your example code above `calendar` **is** the calendar instance (assuming the variable is in scope).

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxxbKxj - notice how I can call the `render()` and `getEvents()` methods by using the calendar variable returned from `new FullCalendar.Calendar`.

N.B. `calendar.view` [gets you the current view object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) specifically.

Comment: When a user first accesses the page the calendar is loaded like you example. But I would then like to filter outside of the calendar scope "var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {" is this event possible?

Comment: Yes. It's just the same as any other JavaScript variable. You can either change the scope of the `calendar` variable (e.g. make it global), or maybe you pass it to some other part of your code as a function parameter or something. How you do it depends on the structure of your code but there's nothing special about the calendar object - just deal with it as you would deal with any other JS variable when you need to use it in another place.